# Sum of powers of a field's element equals zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Assume that we have a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and an element $a\in\mathbb{F}_q$ s.t. $\mathrm{ord}(a)=9$. I want to prove that 
$$1+a^{3}+a^{-3}+1+a^{3}+a^{-3}+1+a^{3}+a^{-3}=0$$
I know that this should hold by some coding theory property but I cannot prove it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I made a mistake so it needs only to hold for $b=0$. I have made the edits. Can you give any hints?

Comment: To begin, divide by $3$. Then let $b=a^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a$ has order $9$, then $a^3$ has order $3$, and so $1,a^3, a^{-3}$ are all different, and each of them is a root of $x^3-1$.

In a field, a nonzero polynomial cannot have more roots than its degree, so $1+a^3+a^{-3}$ is the sum of *the* three roots of $x^3-1$. But the sum of the roots of a monic polynomial (that has the maximal number of roots) is exactly minus the next-to-highest coefficient, which is $0$ in this case.

---

Alternatively, rewrite your goal by multiplying by powers of $a^9$ to
$$ 1+a^3+a^6+\cdots+a^{24}=0 $$
and apply the formula for a finite geometric series, giving
$$ \frac{a^{27}-1}{a^3-1} = 0 $$
But the numerator here is $a^{27}-1=(a^9)^3-1=1^3-1=0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last statement "the sum of the roots of a monic polynomial (that has the maximal number of roots) is exactly minus the next-to-highest coefficient"? It would be nice if you can pinpoint some reference to a proof or related literature.

Comment: @mgus: Such a polynomial splits into linear factors $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$, which multiplies out to $x^3-(a_1+a_2+a_3)x^2+\cdots-a_1a_2a_3$. (If the latter were _not_ the polynomial you're looking at, you could subtract them and get a nonzero polynomial of degree $<3$ which has $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ as roots, but that is impossible).